# What's the difference between two types of diaphragms?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics, microscopy, imaging

What's the principal difference between aperture iris diaphragm and field iris diaphragm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [(Condenser) Aperture Diaphragms](http://zeiss-campus.magnet.fsu.edu/tutorials/basics/condenseraperturefunction/indexflash.html) are placed at or close to the the back-focal plane of the condenser. They control the numerical aperture of the condenser and their conjugate plane is at infinite. Closing it, you reduce the illumination at the sample plane **homogeneously** (like turning up or down the light source).
- [Field Iris Diaphragms](http://zeiss-campus.magnet.fsu.edu/tutorials/basics/fielddiaphragm/indexflash.html) are placed in the illumination path, in a plane conjugate to the sample plane. Closing it, you reduce the illumination at the sample plane **not homogeneously** (clearly seeing the edges of the iris).

(both effects are very clear in the links)